# lazy SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I'm using a SlidingDrawer and it works quite well in my application but... is it possible to have one that doesn't open or close entirely when the handle is touched?
I'll try to explain better: dragging the handle up and down, my SlidingDrawer opens and closes correctly following up my finger but, when I stop touching, the view completes showing or hiding its content by itself (depending on its previous state).
Is it possible to have a SlidingDrawer that behaves exactly as described but, once the touch is released, stop open or close preserving the height shown so far?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code to implement open and close drawer

```
    slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) this.findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer);    
    slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(this); 
    slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(this);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Anand; if i understood, overriding -let me say- the OnDrawerOpenListener i'd be able to prevent the slider to open completely but only a given height?

Comment: yes you can , the only thing is on above layout of drawer if there are some other controls than you can set upto that much and restrict the slider